# Converting WIF as Base58 string to byte array in bash

Tags: private-key, wallet-import-format, bash

I want to convert wif as Base58 string to byte array.

Private key to WIF

```
printf 800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D | xxd -r -p | base58
```

> 5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ

Now I want reverse this (WIF to private key), form `5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ` to `800C28FCA386C7A227600B2FE50B7CAE11EC86D3BF1FBE471BE89827E19D72AA1D507A5B8D`

Im using that library https://github.com/keis/base58 But I can change or better if I can use only bash without extra library

full example https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format

Comment: Are you looking for an alternative tool to decode base58 to hex?

Comment: no the alternative. with this tool I can't to  base58 to hex, or I don't understand How can I that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the decode flag `-d`:

```
printf "5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ" | base58 -c -d | xxd -p
800c28fca386c7a227600b2fe50b7cae11ec86d3bf1fbe471be89827e19d
72aa1d
```

To have `xxd` output all on one line, give it a large column number `-c` flag:

```
$ printf "5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ" | base58 -c -d | xxd -p -c 1000
800c28fca386c7a227600b2fe50b7cae11ec86d3bf1fbe471be89827e19d72aa1d
```

If you really want the checksum included `507A5B8D` (the last 4 bytes), omit the `-c` flag which denotes checksum encoding:

```
$ printf "5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ" | base58 -d | xxd -p -c 1000
800c28fca386c7a227600b2fe50b7cae11ec86d3bf1fbe471be89827e19d72aa1d507a5b8d
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full script which reads the key from standard input so it doesn't get stored in a file or command history, verifies the checksum and key length, and then prints the network byte, secret key, and compressed key flag.

Requires [base58](https://github.com/keis/base58) package to be installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter WIF key: " wif_key
decoded_key=$(echo "$wif_key" | base58 -dc | xxd -p -c 256)
if [ ! -z $decoded_key ]
then
    keylen=$(echo -n $decoded_key | wc -c)
    if [ "$keylen" -ge 66 ] && [ "$keylen" -le 68 ]
    then
        echo "Network byte: ${decoded_key:0:2}";
        echo "Secret key: ${decoded_key:2:64}";
        if [ -z ${decoded_key:66:2} ]; then cpk="false"; else cpk="true"; fi
        echo "Compressed public key: $cpk";
    else
        echo "Invalid decoded key length" >&2
        $(exit 1)
    fi
else
    $(exit 1)
fi
```

#### Example

Prompt:

```
Enter WIF key: 5HueCGU8rMjxEXxiPuD5BDku4MkFqeZyd4dZ1jvhTVqvbTLvyTJ
```

Output:

```
Network byte: 80
Secret key: 0c28fca386c7a227600b2fe50b7cae11ec86d3bf1fbe471be89827e19d72aa1d
Compressed public key: false
```